# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at R3Injector.processProvider (core.mjs:11577:31)

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I encountered this error while trying to navigating through a website I’m working on:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at R3Injector.processProvider (core.mjs:11577:31)
    at core.mjs:11546:56
    at core.mjs:4192:76
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.mjs:4192:11)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.mjs:11546:13)
    at core.mjs:11514:30
    at core.mjs:4192:76
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.mjs:4192:11)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at zone.js:1118:17
    at zone.js:1134:33
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:25719:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at zone.js:1275:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25706:33)
```

The only .push() method inside this module that I can find is from the class below:

```
// Core
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
 
// Applications
import { BlacklistImportActionTypes } from './blacklist-import.actions';
import { BlacklistImportApi } from './blacklist-import.api';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MessageService } from 'src/app/shared/services';
 
@Injectable()
export class BlacklistImportEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private blacklistImportApi: BlacklistImportApi,
    private messageService: MessageService,
  ) { }
 
  getList$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_SEARCH_BLACKLIST_IMPORT),
      switchMap(({ payload }) =>
        this.blacklistImportApi.searchBlacklistImport(payload).pipe(
          map(({ data }) => ({
            type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_SEARCH_BLACKLIST_IMPORT_RESULT,
            payload: data,
          })),
          catchError((err) => {
            return of({
              type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_SEARCH_BLACKLIST_IMPORT_RESULT,
              payload: { error: err.error },
            })
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
 
  checkImportProcess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_CHECK_IMPORT_PROCESS),
      switchMap(({ isOpenImport }) =>
        this.blacklistImportApi.checkImportProcess().pipe(
          switchMap(({ data }) => {
            const actions = [{
              type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_CHECK_IMPORT_PROCESS_RESULT,
              payload: data
            }];
            if (isOpenImport) {
              actions.push({
                type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_OPEN_IMPORT_FORM,
                payload: !data?.totalRow
              })
            }
            return actions;
          })
          ,
          catchError((err) => {
            if (err.error.message) {
              this.messageService.error(err.error.message);
            }
            return of({
              type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_CHECK_IMPORT_PROCESS_RESULT,
              payload: { error: err.error },
            })
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
 
  importCase$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_IMPORT_BLACKLIST),
      switchMap(({ payload }) =>
        this.blacklistImportApi.importBlacklist(payload).pipe(
          map(({data}) => ({
            type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_IMPORT_RESULT,
            payload: data,
          })),
          catchError((err) => {
            if (err.error.message) {
              this.messageService.error(err.error.message);
            }
            return of({
              type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_IMPORT_RESULT,
              payload: { error: err.error },
            })
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

I have very little experience of Angular in general and got assigned this at work. My task is just simply cloning this module from another existing similar module.
I tried asking Google Bard AI about this and it said I imported the wrong Actions (which was not the case here).
I put a console.log before the .push() method but there was nothing printed on the console output, so how could this error occur even if it was never reached?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in your HTML, not your your TS code.  Your output looks like the code has been minified, so it's hard to know for sure, but 90% of the time it's because the HTML is trying to call a method (or access a property) of something that doesn't exist, or doesn't exist yet.

In Angular, the HTML is often ready and calling things before the component is fully initialized, before an input binding is available, or before a service call has returned.

For that reason, it's fairly common practice to put an *ngIf in the outermost div (or other element) that accesses the thing that may not be ready yet.

For example:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @Input()
  public myObject: any;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="myObject">
  ...
 </div>
```

In this way the HTML won't try to render anything that relies on myObject before it is available.

Comment: I commented all the HTML one by one, and then proceeded to comment all of them but I still got the error unfortunately…

Answer (score 0):

In the `checkImportProcess$` effect, you're trying to dispatch an action by pushing it to `actions` which is a different pattern than you used beforehand (note the `map`/`switchMap` Operators)

```js
// Instead of this:
actions.push({
  type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_OPEN_IMPORT_FORM,
  payload: !data?.totalRow
});

// Consider dispatching the action like this:
return {
  type: BlacklistImportActionTypes.REQUEST_OPEN_IMPORT_FORM,
  payload: !data?.totalRow
};
```

I reckon your error happens because you try to push to the *actions* property of Type `Actions` which is not really an array but rather the datastructure ngrx uses to notfiy everything store-related about new actions that were dispatched.